# Parse editing object after relational query

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8, pfquery, pfobject

In my application the user creates a PFObject in the alarm class that has a relation to the current user. I would like to retrieve it and edit it.

Adding the object:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
PFObject *alarm = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Alerts"];
alarm[@"Active"] = @YES;
alarm[@"ActionWasCompleted"] = @NO;
alarm[@"Time"] = _alarmTime;

PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"user"];
[relation addObject:user];
[alarm saveInBackground];
```

Retrieving the user specific object and editing it:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Alerts"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d objects.", objects.count);
        [[objects objectAtIndex:0] setObject:@YES forKey:@"ActionWasCompleted"];
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Now I have used relational queries before I haven't edited them, but I cant even seem to retrieve the objects in the alarm class related to the current user. Let alone edit the object. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

All I would like to do is create a PFObject that is specific to the user, retrieve it and edit it.

If you have any suggestions I'm all ears! Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I figured out how to save the queried object using

```
[PFObject saveAllInBackground:objects];
```

But I'm still unable to retrieve objects related to the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your Alerts creation code, you have a 1:m relationship between User->Alerts (oddly, via the `PFUser`'s `user` field), but no relationship from Alerts->User (or if you do, it's not set). You can still query all Alerts for a given User, but you have to do so from querying via the User, rather than via the Alerts.

Also, you might want to check the relationship - it looks like your `PFUser` has a field called "user" which you're using as a relationship to the Alerts. I'd recommend renaming that to Alerts, just so it's clear what the relationship is to.

```
PFRelation *alertsRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"user"]; // Should rename the relation on the user so it's clear what it's a relation to
PFQuery *alertsQuery = [alertsRelation query];
[alertsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *alerts, NSError *error) {
  // alerts now contains the the Alerts for the current PFUser
}];
```

Just another thought - if you're expecting your relationship to the user is being set on the Alert via a relation field with the name user, you should change your object adding code from

```
PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"user"];
[relation addObject:user];
[alarm saveInBackground];
```

to

```
PFRelation *relation = [alarm relationForKey:@"user"];
[relation addObject:user];
[alarm saveInBackground];
```

If you do this, then your original query code should work, as the user relationship on the Alerts is now being set.

Comment: Thanks I will try this when I get home.

Comment: Thank you I just changed the relation where the object was being created and it worked!